# Template Inheritance in Golang

Tags: go, go-templates

I am trying to inherit a **base** template into my **home* page file in **Golang**

My directory structure:

```
project_root
  /templates
    /layouts
        base.layout.html
    /pages
        home.page.html
```

[Gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) router configuration:

```
router.LoadHTMLGlob("./templates/layouts/*.layout.html")
router.LoadHTMLGlob("./templates/pages/*.page.html")
```

templates/layouts/base.layout.html file:

```
{{define "base"}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{.Title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{block "content" .}} {{end}}
</body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

templates/pages/ho,e.page.html file:

```
{{template "base" .}}

{{define "page-title"}}
    Home
{{end}}
{{end}}
```

The error I am getting:

> Error #01: html/template:home.page.html:1:11: no such template "base"

***NOTE: If I removed the inheritance, the home page loads*** fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Don't make 2 different calls to `LoadHTMLGlob`, instead just use:

```golang
router.LoadHTMLGlob("./templates/**/*.html")
```

#### Explanation

Your issue here is caused by the fact the 2nd call to `LoadHTMLGlob` completely overwrites what the 1st call have loaded. This is because:

- `LoadHTMLGlob` calls `engine.SetHTMLTemplate(templ)`: https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/v1.9.1/gin.go#L263
- `SetHTMLTemplate` **assigns** `engine.HTMLRender`: https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/v1.9.1/gin.go#L284

Therefore, the contents of `engine.HTMLRender` at the end of the 2 calls to `LoadHTMLGlob` in your code is the same as if you were only calling `LoadHTMLGlob("./templates/pages/*.page.html")`. So it's normal that `base` does not exist, because it's defined in `./templates/layouts/*.layout.html`.

This is why you should only make one call to `LoadHTMLGlob`.

#### About your templates

Also, I don't know what you're trying to achieve here, but `page-title` defined in `home.page.html` is not used in `base.layout.html`, you have `.Title` instead. In case your Go code is:

```golang
router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "home.page.html", gin.H{})
})
```

Then you can use `page-title` in your layout (instead of `.Title`):

```
-    <title>{{.Title}}</title>
+    <title>{{block "page-title" .}} {{end}}</title>
```

And define it in your home page like this:

```
{{template "base" .}}

{{define "page-title"}}
    Home
{{end}}

{{define "content"}}
    Welcome to my website!
{{end}}
```

When accessing `/`, you'll then get a webpage with the title `Home` and the body contents equal to `Welcome to my website!`.